# Array elements change automatically when I enter a function

Tags: c++

I am implementing a graph. I have print, BFS and DFS methods. My print, BFS, and DFS would work normally if I run them separately, however, if I run them one after another one, for example, I ran BFS after print, the BFS won't work. It seems I changed my array in my methods but I did not, can anyone help me with this?

below is my graph.h

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
#include <queue>
using namespace std;

struct node{
    char ID;
    int WEIGHT;
    int DISTANCE;
    bool VISITED;
    node(char,int);
    node *next;
};
struct  myGraph{
public:
    void addEdge(node* [], char,char,int);
    void printGraph(node* [], int V);
    void BFS(node* [],char);
    void visitedNode(node* [], char head, int);
    void DFS(node* [],char);
};
```

below is my graph.cpp

```
#include "myGraph.h"

node::node(char id, int weight) {
    this->ID = id;
    this->WEIGHT = weight;
    this->VISITED = false;
    this->DISTANCE = 0;
    this->next = nullptr;

}

void myGraph::addEdge(node* adj[], char head, char end, int weight)
{   int parent = head - 'a';
    node* newNode = new node(head,0);
    node* anotherNode = new node(end,weight);
    if (adj[parent] == nullptr){
        adj[parent] = newNode;
        adj[parent]->next = anotherNode;
    }
    else{
        node *temp = adj[parent];
        while(temp->next != nullptr){

            temp = temp->next;
        }
        temp->next= anotherNode;
    }
}

void myGraph::printGraph(node* adj[], int V)
{
    for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
    {
        if (adj[v] != nullptr){
            cout << "Adjacency list: "<<endl;
            cout<<"Head: "<<adj[v]->ID<<" -> ";
            while (adj[v]->next != nullptr){
                adj[v]= adj[v]->next;
                cout <<"Id: "<<adj[v]->ID <<" Weight: "<<adj[v]->WEIGHT<<" -> ";

            }
            cout<<"nullptr"<<endl;
        }
    }
}
void myGraph::visitedNode(node* adj[], char target, int size){
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++){
        node* temp =  adj[i];
        while (temp != nullptr){
            if (temp->ID == target){
                temp->VISITED = true;
            }
            temp = temp->next;
        }
    }
}


void myGraph::BFS(node* adj[],char head) {
    queue<node*> temp;
    vector<node*> result;
    node * tempNode = adj[head-'a']; //assign head pointer to tempNode
    temp.push(tempNode);
    visitedNode(adj,tempNode->ID,9);
    while (!temp.empty()){
        tempNode = adj[temp.front()->ID - 'a'];
        temp.pop();
        result.push_back(tempNode);
        while(tempNode->next != nullptr){
            if (!tempNode->VISITED){
                temp.push(tempNode);
                visitedNode(adj,tempNode->ID,9);
            }
            tempNode = tempNode->next;
        }
        if (!tempNode->VISITED){
            temp.push(tempNode);
            visitedNode(adj,tempNode->ID,9);
        }
    }
    cout<<"Traverse by BFS: "<<endl;
    for (auto i : result){
        cout<<i->ID <<" ";
    }
}


void myGraph::DFS(node* adj[],char head){
    stack<node*> temp;
    vector<node*> result;
    node * tempNode = adj[head-'a'];
    temp.push(tempNode);
    visitedNode(adj,tempNode->ID,9);
    while(!temp.empty()){
        while (tempNode->next != nullptr){
            if (!tempNode->next->VISITED){
                tempNode = adj[tempNode->next->ID - 'a'];
                visitedNode(adj,tempNode->ID,9);
                temp.push(tempNode);
            }
            else{
                tempNode = tempNode->next;
            }

        }
        result.push_back(temp.top());
        temp.pop();
        if (!temp.empty()){
            tempNode = temp.top();
        }
    }


    cout<<"Traverse by DFS: "<<endl;
    for (auto i : result){
        cout<<i->ID <<" ";
    }
}
```

below is my main

```
#include "main.h"
int main() {
    myGraph *tryme = new myGraph();
    const int V = 9;
    node* adj[V] = {};
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'a','b',2);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'a','c',4);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'a','d',6);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'b','c',5);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'b','a',2);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'c','b',5);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'c','d',1);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'c','e',2);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'c','a',4);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'd','h',4);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'd','f',3);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'd','c',1);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'd','a',6);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'e','c',2);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'e','i',3);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'e','g',5);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'e','f',1);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'f','g',4);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'f','e',1);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'f','d',3);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'g','e',5);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'g','f',4);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'h','d',4);
    tryme->addEdge(adj, 'i','e',3);

    tryme->printGraph(adj, V);
    tryme->DFS(adj,'a');
    tryme->BFS(adj,'a');
```

If I only call print, or only call DFS, or only call BFS, the code works fun, if I call them one by one, below is the output

```
Adjacency list: 
Head: a -> Id: b Weight: 2 -> Id: c Weight: 4 -> Id: d Weight: 6 -> nullptr
Adjacency list: 
Head: b -> Id: c Weight: 5 -> Id: a Weight: 2 -> nullptr
Adjacency list: 
Head: c -> Id: b Weight: 5 -> Id: d Weight: 1 -> Id: e Weight: 2 -> Id: a 
Weight: 4 -> nullptr
Adjacency list: 
Head: d -> Id: h Weight: 4 -> Id: f Weight: 3 -> Id: c Weight: 1 -> Id: a 
Weight: 6 -> nullptr
Adjacency list: 
Head: e -> Id: c Weight: 2 -> Id: i Weight: 3 -> Id: g Weight: 5 -> Id: f 
Weight: 1 -> nullptr
Adjacency list: 
Head: f -> Id: g Weight: 4 -> Id: e Weight: 1 -> Id: d Weight: 3 -> nullptr
Adjacency list: 
Head: g -> Id: e Weight: 5 -> Id: f Weight: 4 -> nullptr
Adjacency list: 
Head: h -> Id: d Weight: 4 -> nullptr
Adjacency list: 
Head: i -> Id: e Weight: 3 -> nullptr
Traverse by DFS: 
d Traverse by BFS: 
a d
```

Comment: Suggestion, start by making your classes const-correct. For example a `print` function should take const arguments.

Comment: Please use a debugger and single-step through your code to see where it goes wrong.  Writing all of this code and hoping it works, and if it doesn't work, just take guesses as to what to change, is not the way to go about this.  Using the debugger is part and parcel of how to write programs.

Comment: @alfC: not too useful as his graph class does not contain the graph -- just functions that operate on a graph in an external array,

Comment: @ChrisDodd In that case, then functions should be static or inside a namespace instead of a class.

Answer (score 1):

Your `printGraph` method is modifying the graph while it prints it, removing all of the edges.  The line `adj[v]= adj[v]->next;` will remove the Node at the head of the list `adj[v]`.  So if you do anything with the graph afterwards, it won't work as you expect.

Besisde that, your data structures are strange and not object oriented.  Your `myGraph` class does not contain the graph; you pass it as an argument to all the methods.  You should instead restructure things to make `adj` a member of myGraph.  This will be much easier if you use a std::vector instead of a raw array.

Comment: thanks for your reply, do you have any idea where I changed my array in DFS and BFS? I tried to debug, no luck, stackoverflow is my last resort...